# issue with if #available SwiftUI less than iOS 14

Tags: swiftui

I'm using the beta version of Xcode 12.0 to play around with LazyVGrid, to render this grid within a scrollview if the phone has iOS 14, otherwise just to render the ScrollView as one column.

When I launch this on the app on my phone (not using iOS 14), opening this view causes my app to crash. But if I comment out the "if #available" section and just display what's in the "else" statement, it works fine.

Is there an issue with if #available in earlier versions of iOS or is my syntax just incorrect?

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                //Empty View navigation link to choose the selected pack in User Defaults.
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    //Checks if iOS version 14.0 is available to render the lazy grid view
                    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {

                        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 15) {
                                //checks if the pack is in the purchased list - if so, renders it as an unlocked tile.
                            ForEach((allPacks), id: \.self) { pack in
                                    UnlockedPackTile(tilePack: pack)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            print("Originally tapped \(pack.name)")
                                            self.userInformation.defaultPack = pack
                                            self.isPresented.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                            //does this as a simple stack instead if iOS 14 is not available.
                            ForEach((allPacks), id: \.self) { pack in
                                    UnlockedPackTile(tilePack: pack)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            print("Originally tapped \(pack.name)")
                                            self.userInformation.defaultPack = pack
                                            self.isPresented.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap content of `ScrollView` into `Group` (or `VStack`) like

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
   Group {
      if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
          // ... new content here
      } else {
          // ... old content here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried putting it in a Group, and that didn't seem to fix it, but I'm not sure what you mean by the comment about this if not being at the body level? It is contained in the body within a view structure. Is that the problem?